# Defining global variables over multiple files outside main loop

Tags: c++

I know it's not very good, but I need global variables across multiple files in my program. These are my graphics window's variables:

- Name
- Size
- Status

.

I know I can make a `.h` file and declare all variables:

```
#pragma once

extern std::string GameName;
extern sf::RenderWindow Window;
extern std::string Status;
```

.

Then I want to define my variables in my `main.cpp`, so all files can access these values. But I cannot define these unless they are in the `int main()` loop. Is there another way, so I can define these variables not in main loop?

**EDIT**

Using Visual Studio 2017.
Errors:

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "class sf::RenderWindow Window"
>   (?Window@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A)   Cubes
>   Library   C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Files\Libraries\Cubes
>   Library\Cubes Library\Cubes Library.obj   1

.

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > Status"
>   (?Status@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)   Cubes
>   Library   C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Files\Libraries\Cubes
>   Library\Cubes Library\Cubes Library.obj   1

.

> LNK1120   2 unresolved externals  Cubes
>   Library   C:\Users\George\Documents\C++\Files\Libraries\Cubes
>   Library\Debug\Cubes Library.dll   1

Comment: "but I need global variables across multiple files in my program" - no, you don't.

Comment: What do you mean by "defining your variables in main loop"? Show us some code.

Comment: _"But I cannot define these unless they are in the int main() loop. Is there another way, so I can define these variables not in main loop?"_ Don't know what this means.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare them in your main.cpp file, but in order to make them globally accessible, you have to define them outside your main function/loop.  If you decalre them inside your main function/loop, they are local variables and cannot (easily) be accessed globally.  Doing it this way combined with the header file you suggested will work.

```
// Global variables...
std::string GameName;
sf::RenderWindow Window;
std::string Status;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

You could also put them in another file, for example globals.cpp.

Comment: Generally you should avoid global variables if you can, but it is not always possible.   In C++ I generally prefer to declare them in a class (called something like Program, Application, etc.) that is either a global variable or a singleton.

Comment: I want to use the variables across multiple files, so this example won't work. This will only make them global to this file. How can I combine this with the header file?

Comment: When you include the header file you suggested in other files it will help them "resolve" the variables when compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You would do it like this...

File: Main.h

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <string>

extern std::string GameName; 
//extern sf::RenderWindow Window;
extern std::string Status;

#endif
```

File: Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "Main.h"

std::string GameName;
//sf::RenderWindow Window; 
std::string Status;

extern void foo(); // Function Prototype

int main()
{
    GameName = "none";
    Status = "none";

    foo();

    std::cout << GameName << " - " << Status << std::endl;

    std::cout << "(HIT A KEY TO CONTINUE)" << std::endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

File: Other.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "Main.h"

void foo()
{
    // Global variables declared in Main.cpp are now accessible here
    GameName = "Horizon New Dawn";
    Status = "Finished";
}
```

Comment: I am getting the `unresolved external symbol` errors

Comment: Can you post the entire error message?  What compiler, IDE, etc. are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017. I get these three "fatal" errors (edited question)

Comment: OK, I just modified my example code.  I'm not really set up to use RenderWindow, but I created a new C++ console app containing those 3 files and it work as expected.   Are you trying to build those variables into a library (DLL?) and use them from a different application?  Can you upload your entire project someplace and provide a link?

Comment: I am using a DLL. I have `ZigZag.cpp` (main project), `Global Library` DLL, and `Cubes Library` DLL. The DLL's will be shared between many projects. The problem is with the `Cubes Library`, because these are the errors that appear when I build the `.h` and `.cpp` from the DLL.

Comment: My code is therefore in `.h` files in the DLL, with the corresponding `.cpp` file with the code `#include "stdafx.h" [New line] #include "[Name] Library.h"`

Comment: OK, sorry, I don't think you made that clear in the question.  I've written quite a few DLLs, but I've never had to do that.  I think you can still do it by marking them with dllexport and/or dllimport, let me see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to do it using globals in a DLL.

// File: DLLGlobals.h

```
// This file is used in the DLL project
#ifndef __GLOBALS_H__
#define __GLOBALS_H__

#include <string>

extern "C"
{
    extern __declspec(dllexport) std::string GameName;
    extern __declspec(dllexport) std::string Status;
}

#endif//__GLOBALS_H__
```

// File: DLLGlobals.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "DLLGlobals.h"

extern "C"
{
    // Define Global Variables (no C++ mangling)
    __declspec(dllexport) std::string GameName = "Dishonored 2";
    __declspec(dllexport) std::string Status = "Not Started";
}
```

// File: DLL.h

```
#ifndef __DLL_H__
#define __DLL_H__

// This file is included by code using the DLL project
#include <string>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllimport) std::string GameName;
    __declspec(dllimport) std::string Status;
}

#endif//__DLL_H__
```

// File: Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "Main.h"

#include "<path_to_dll_header>\DLL.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << GameName << ": " << Status << std::endl;

    std::cout << "(HIT A KEY TO CONTINUE)" << std::endl;
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your excellent help! Almost done - 1) In the `main.cpp` file, what is `main.h` and what should it contain? 2) Where does `DLLGlobals.h` come in or get included? Have you put `main.h` instead of this by accident?

Comment: Main.h is empty is empty in this example, it is a left over from the previous example.  DLLGlobals.h comes from your dll (library) project and contains definitions (that you must add) for any program that wants to use your library.  You can call it anything you want, I just called it that to help indicate where it was coming from.